# Cancelling PendingIntent | code has no effect

Tags: java, android

Trying to disable an Alarm using `PendingIntent` . However code doesn't seems to have any error, but it doesn't work. Here's what I did.

From one Activity I initiated alarm:

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
{
    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("ALARM_NO", tempx);
    alarmintent.setAction("my.action.string");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


}
```

And from Another Activity I am trying to kill the Alarm, however doing so doesn't yield the desired output, rather the Alarm is played at the set time.
Here is the code:

```
public void alarmSet1(View view)
{

    int a1=1;
    int idTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.w("myApp", "SAVED VALUE IS:"+idTime);



    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra("pendInt", idTime);
        intent.putExtra("tts", a1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else
    {


        SharedPreferences sa = getSharedPreferences("TimesList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int rec = sa.getInt("ID1",0);
        Log.w("myApp", "RECEIVED VALUE IS:"+rec);


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
                rec, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Any fix/solution will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: What is `pen` (in `setAlarm()`), what is `rec` (in `alarmSet1()`), and are you sure that they are the same value? Also, try replacing `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` with `0`.

Comment: oh, `pen` is the uniqueID , `rec`  and `pen` are same, SInce it involves multiple activities i just passed the Ids using Extras and SharedPreferences, the values are equal, checked

Comment: tried with `0` . No use :(

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `pendingIntent.cancel()`, just `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntnet);'

When you're deleting the alarm and make `myIntent`, call `myIntent.setAction("my.action.string")` before making the pendingIntent.

Comment: Oh! You might need to add alarmintent.setAction("my.action.string"); to your intent when deleting to have them match.

Comment: Can you please explain or any link to that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: When you're deleting the alarm and make "myIntent", use "myIntent.setAction("my.action.string")" before making the pendingIntent.

Comment: Forgive if I am asking for more, if you can edit your answer, that'd be great